# mjolnic fontawesome-iconpicker how set selected value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, font-awesome

I'm using this amazing jQuery plugin to select fontawesome icons, managed to retrieve the item selected through an event that was triggered, but have no idea on how to set this value programmatically, anyone have any ideas ?

I'm just starting out in jquery so maybe it's a simple thing .

Link of the plugin: https://github.com/mjolnic/fontawesome-iconpicker

code inside the plugin who i think it is changing the value of the selected item :

```
setValue: function(a) {
        var b = this.getValid(a);
        if (b !== false) {
            this.iconpickerValue = b;
            this._trigger("iconpickerSetValue", {
                iconpickerValue: b
            });
            return this.iconpickerValue;
        } else {
            this._trigger("iconpickerInvalid", {
                iconpickerValue: a
            });
            return false;
        }
    },
```

I don't know how to call this method.
Tanks for anyone help

Answer (score 1):

i use `update` function, for use

```
$('.icp-dd').data('iconpicker').update("NameIcon", true);
```